# Code to split text file based on string not working, compiles fine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with some data. Each line in the text file specifies a date, and there are multiple lines with the same date. I wrote the following code to split the text file into individual files based on the dates, for a number of pre-determined dates.

```py
f=open("2014 IONOSONDE.txt", 'r')
Dates = ["01-20-2014","01-21-2014","01-22-2014","01-24-2014","03-31-2014","04-01-2014","04-02-2014","04-02-2014","04-03-2014","04-04-2014","04-22-2014","04-23-2014","04-24-2014","04-25-2014","05-05-2014","05-06-2014","05-07-2014","05-08-2014","09-22-2014","09-23-2014","09-24-2014","09-25-2014","09-26-2014","11-25-2014","11-26-2014","11-27-2014","12-15-2014","12-16-2014","12-17-2014","12-18-2014","12-19-2014","12-20-2014","12-21-2014","12-22-2014"]
for i in range(0,34):
    fw=open(str(Dates[i])+".txt",'w')
    for line in f:
        if Dates[i] in line:
            print(line)
            fw.write(line)
fw.close()
f.close()
```

The code compile fine and individual files are made but there are no data in any of these individual files. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I am an absolute beginner to programming and don't really care about the elegance of the code as long as it gets the work done.

The input text file looks like:
[Input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V871.png)

The output files should look the same except that its exclusive to one specific date (From the ones mentioned in the code).

Comment: Please share and example of the input file and output file

Comment: Files don't necessarily flush the data to disk immediately. You are recycling fw multiple times. Move fw.close() after you exit the inner loop (that should force data flushing).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [with statement](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python) to avoid those kind of conflicts:

```
dates = ["01-20-2014","01-21-2014","01-22-2014","01-24-2014","03-31-2014","04-01-2014","04-02-2014","04-02-2014","04-03-2014","04-04-2014","04-22-2014","04-23-2014","04-24-2014","04-25-2014","05-05-2014","05-06-2014","05-07-2014","05-08-2014","09-22-2014","09-23-2014","09-24-2014","09-25-2014","09-26-2014","11-25-2014","11-26-2014","11-27-2014","12-15-2014","12-16-2014","12-17-2014","12-18-2014","12-19-2014","12-20-2014","12-21-2014","12-22-2014"]

with open("2014 IONOSONDE.txt", 'r') as f:
    for i in range(0,34):
        with open(str(dates[i])+".txt",'w+') as fw:
            for line in f:
                if dates[i] in line:
                    print(line)
                    fw.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked in the end. I had to change the position of for loop as well as remove zeroes in the dates.

```py
dates = ["1-20-2014","1-21-2014","1-22-2014","1-24-2014","3-31-2014", "4-1-2014","4-2-2014","4-2-2014","4-3-2014","4-4-2014","4-22-2014","4-23-2014","4-24-2014","4-25-2014","5-5-2014","5-6-2014","5-7-2014","5-8-2014","9-22-2014","9-23-2014","9-24-2014","9-25-2014","9-26-2014","11-25-2014","11-26-2014","11-27-2014","12-15-2014","12-16-2014","12-17-2014","12-18-2014","12-19-2014","12-20-2014","12-21-2014","12-22-2014"]
for i in range(0,34):
    f=open("2014 IONOSONDE.txt",'r')
    with open(str(dates[i])+".txt",'w+') as fw:     
        for line in f:
            y=str(dates[i])
            if y in line:
                print(line)
                fw.write(line)
```